# Is there a way to use a declared variable in BigQuery SQL with ROWS BETWEEN 'variable' PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW in a window function?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Currently getting the error "Window framing expression must be a literal or parameter at [x:x]", it works fine using just the number 5 but this is used a lot throughout my script.

```
DECLARE variable INT64;
SET variable = 5;

SELECT col1, value, time, 
                CASE
                    WHEN "Bla" = "Bla"
                    THEN MIN(value) OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY time ROWS BETWEEN variable PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) 
                    ELSE NULL
                    END 
                AS MinVal

FROM data
```

Comment: I have a similar use case where I want to specify `RANGE BETWEEN column PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`, where `column` is an integer column that exists in the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use execute immediate to execute dynamic queries. For eg. Below query uses var in over clause.

[EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#execute_immediate)

```
declare var int64 default 5;

execute immediate

'select min(1) over(order by street_number ROWS BETWEEN '||var||' PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) from' ||'`bigquery-public-data.austin_311.311_service_requests` limit 100'
```